# Making an Average of Grades in C

Tags: c, arrays, enums, int, structure

**Note: I am a beginner and am just learning.**

I have student structure with 5 names, their grades, their ages, and an their grades. I would like to know how to write and call a function that will calculate the average of their grades, and then print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    int scores[5];
} student;

student grade(student st, int grade, int num) {
    st.scores[num]=grade;
    return st;
}

int main(){
    student s1;
    strcpy(s1.name, "Student1");

    s1.age = 20;

    //printf("Size: %d\n", sizeof(s1));
    printf("Name: %s\tAge: %d\n", s1.name, s1.age);

    s1=grade(s1, 100, 0);
    s1=grade(s1, 96, 1);
    s1=grade(s1, 99, 2);    
    s1=grade(s1, 100, 3);

    printf("Grade: %d\n", s1.scores[0]);
    printf("Grade: %d\n", s1.scores[1]);
    printf("Grade: %d\n", s1.scores[2]);
    printf("Grade: %d\n", s1.scores[3]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Typos: `s2=grade(s1, 94, 0);` and the next 3 lines should read `s2=grade(s2 ...` and simillary the 4 `s3 = ` lines.

Comment: add the grades and divide....what's the problem?

Comment: @WeatherVane I just changed it, thanks

Comment: @SouravGhosh How do I have the computer do that?

Comment: @user1049876 Your question is unclear? Do you mean you want to calculate the average grade for each student? In that case you can add a new member in `student` struct called `average`, like `double average;`. Then you can define a function `double calc_average(student st)` which will calculate the average and return it back. You can call that function like this , `stdent1.average = calc_average(student1);`.

Comment: what do you mean how to? You know how to add variables and divide, what's stopping you? Sorry, I'm really not clear with your problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a **function to know the average of grades of sent structure** this way:

```
float average(student st, int no_of_grades)
{
    float sum=0;
    for(int num=0 ; num < no_of_grades ; num++)
    {
        sum += st.scores[num];
    }

    return sum/no_of_grades;
}
```

Here the arguments are the structure and number of grades entered for student.

---

After printing all the grades of the student in `main()`, add this statement:

```
printf("average of %s : %f",s1.name,average(s1,4)); //average(structure,  no of grades)
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Student1  Age: 20
Grade: 100
Grade: 96
Grade: 99
Grade: 100
average of Student1 : 98.750000
```

---

**Suggestions:**

- Don't use `int main()`, instead use `int main(void)` as no arguments are being sent into `main()` function. But, in first case that is `int main()`, any number of arguments can be sent into `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new member to `student structure` like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    int scores[5];
    double average;   /* new member */
} student;
```

Define a new function to calculate average for a student and return it back, like this:

```
double calc_average(student st)
{
    int i;
    double sum = 0.0;

    /* Calculate sum of 5 scores */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        sum = sum + st.scores[i];

    /* Return average */
    return sum / 5;
}
```

Then in `main`  - (once you add all the scores for a student) - , you can call this function to get the average score, like this:

```
student1.average = calc_average(student1);
```

Comment: You'll also need a member saying *how many* scores. OP's code only entered 4 of the 5 possible scores.

Comment: Yes,  I saw that in OP's code too :). Thats why I wrote `once you add all the scores for a student`, by which I meant OP would add all 5 scores.

Comment: Well if you are adding new struct members, you could add `int numscores` and remove the last argument of function `grade()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Which function `grade()`, you mean `calc_average()`? There I am passing only one argument. But just in case you want to improve the answer, you can edit it for good :).

Comment: Passing by value of this 130+ byte `student` is not so  great, better to pass   a pointer to it.

Comment: @chux true... i just didnt want to bring pointers into picture.. seemed to me like OP was not able to calculate average of 5 numbers, and given this background, i thought pointers would make it difficult for OP to understand ...

Answer (score -2):

You can hardcore the average perhaps as for example s3.scores[3]